# Force relative sheet reference?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook containing many sheets, one of which is essentially a sign-in sheet. Every row has a Name cell, which has a Data Validation drop down list that references a separate sheet, List Filler. Adjacent cells then use VLOOKUP, referencing the Name cell, and fetch the desired values (ID, phone number, etc.). This works quite well.

I have a macro that splits the workbook into individual worksheets. Easy way to put it is instead of me e-mailing the whole workbook, I just split it and e-mail the sign-in sheet. To facilitate the referencing from Sign In Sheet to List Filler, I copied the List Filler sheet to the new Sign In Sheet workbook.

```
...
xWs.Copy
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
...
masterWB.Sheets("List Filler").Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
...
```

When I open the new workbook, both the List Filler and Sign In Sheet are visible, as expected. However, the VLOOKUP references and the Data Validation Source reference all point to the master workbook:

Data Validation Source changed to:

```
='[workbookname.xlsm]List Filler'!#REF!
```

VLOOKUP changed to:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(O14,'[workbookname.xlsm]List Filler'!A:M,12,FALSE),"")
```

So the VLOOKUP maintained its reference, but absolutely referenced the List Filler sheet in the master workbook.

Basically, I have 2 problems.

1) The VLOOKUP reference needs to relatively reference the List Filler sheet, not look for it in the master workbook. I could fix this with a custom function (how I do it elsewhere), but the fix here is probably the same as for (2), which is what is crippling me.

2) The Data Validation Source reference HAS to be directed towards the "local" List Filler sheet, not the original one in the master workbook.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. If any clarification is needed, please just let me know, and I am also happy to provide more code snippets if needed.

Thanks!

Edit 1:
Just to add, I am wanting to keep the List Filler reference "local" because the Sign In Sheet will eventually be moved/copied back to the master workbook. The Sign In Sheet will go from the master workbook to its own and then back to the master, all while needing access to the List Filler sheet, which will always exist as List Filler in whatever workbook Sign In Sheet is in. Just like we do $A$1 to ALWAYS reference A1, I want to do '$List Filler', if that makes sense.

Comment: For the second problem you could do a find-replace on "[workbookname.xlsm]" and replace it with ""

Comment: For the first one, I'd play around with naming the range in the master workbook, then deleting the named range in the new workbook and adding a new one in the new workbook with the same name.  Then use the named range in the data validation instead of listing the cells.  I don't know if this would work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This might cause a warning to be issued when you do the copy...something like "Do you want to use the named range from the initial workbook," but you could probably suppress the warning and then deal with it.

Comment: Added edit with some more info. For problem (1) I could find/replace, but the more efficient way would be creating a function, but it would still leave problem (2). Not preferred, but maybe if I made a Reset Data Validation macro that is intended to be run after the sheet is moved to a new workbook? Could automate it going out, but would need a button to click after moving it in...

Comment: Could try using named ranges and see how that works.  You might need to mess with the named ranges, but it would be more efficient at least.

Comment: Wow. I'll admit, I'm surprised, but I shouldn't be as I've never used named ranges before. It worked. It looks like it saves it to all sheets and the preferred definition is the one in the current workbook (as opposed to external). Still need to play with it a little, will up vote once verified. Thanks!

Comment: @OpiesDad Go ahead and post a solution and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't really have the time to actually write the code or test it which is why I didn't make an answer.  Since you have a solution, feel free to post it as an answer to your own question.  If this is solved, it's not really worth my time to make a complete answer if you already made it work anyways.  Thanks for looking out though!

Answer (score 0):

Posting on behalf of @OpiesDad

Instead of referencing the range as:

```
'List Filler'!A:M
```

or something similar, define a Named Range which will prevent the referencing of an external workbook as long as the reference exists locally as explained in the problem.

It may be best to have a Dynamic Named Range, which is simply Inserting a Table at the desired range and then naming it based on the table's references, such as

```
Tablename[[SomeVar:AnotherVar]]
```

This allows you to add entries to the Data Validation List without running the risk of blank spaces or missed data.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to replace the links in your new workbook. So it could work, the new workbook must be saved. If the workbook is'n saved you could say it's saved.

```
    masterWB.Sheets("List Filler").Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)
    ...
    newWB.Saved = True
    newWB.ChangeLink Name:=masterWB.Name, NewName:=newWB.Name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
    newWB.Saved = False
```

It worked fine for me on Excel2013.